# PyQt5 5.8.2 build from source on Windows 10

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, nmake

I am using Python 3.6 with Qt 5.8's qmake and VS2017's nmake for the attempt to build PyQt5 from source.

However, I have encountered errors like the following with the first step of

`python configure.py --verbose` :

```
C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qalgorithms.h(593): error C3615: constexpr function 'QAlgorithmsPrivate::qt_builtin_ctz' cannot result in a constant expression
C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qalgorithms.h(595): note: failure was caused by an uninitialized variable declaration
C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qalgorithms.h(595): note: see usage of 'result'
C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qalgorithms.h(596): note: failure was caused by an illegal statement or expression
C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qalgorithms.h(600): error C3615: constexpr function 'QAlgorithmsPrivate::qt_builtin_clz' cannot result in a constant expression
C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qalgorithms.h(602): note: failure was caused by an uninitialized variable declaration
C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qalgorithms.h(602): note: see usage of 'result'
C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qalgorithms.h(603): note: failure was caused by an illegal statement or expression
.
.
.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Note: I do have PyQt5 successfully installed using `pip install PyQt5` later on and it is working fine. But I am just unable to figure it out why the error is occurring and I would still like to solve it to avoid the same problem in the future.

Comment: Try asking the author on the PyQt mailing list.

Comment: Possibly related to [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59575). Do you actually need to build with VS2017? Since you're using a VS2015 build of Qt you should probably be building PyQt with the same to avoid using multiple MSVC runtimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon [user3419537 's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703144/pyqt5-5-8-2-build-from-source-on-windows-10#comment74529218_43703144), it seems like building and compiling through VS2015 works just fine.